# Trying to scrollTop to a server side rendered ID hash location

Tags: jquery

I have server side code which has an ID attached to it as an id attribute. However when I append the ID to the URL and try to scroll to it, it does the animation, but doesn't scroll to the correct ID. I've searched multiple threads but they all have the same answer and I'm not understand why it isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var selector = $('.tab-panels li.active');
        if (selector.hasClass('active')) {
            var panelToShow = $(selector).attr('rel');
            $('#' + panelToShow).toggle(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            var hash = url.split('#').pop();
            history.pushState(null, null, '?' + panelToShow + '#' + hash);
            var target = '#' + hash;
            console.log(target);

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                }, 1000);

            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        } else {
            var selector = $('.tab-panels li:nth-of-type(1)');
            var panelToShow = $(selector).attr('rel');
            $('#' + panelToShow).toggle(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            var url = location.hash;
            var hash = url.split('#').pop();
            console.log(hash);
            history.pushState(null, null, '?' + panelToShow + '#' + hash);
            var target = '#' + hash;
                console.log(target);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                }, 1000);
            $(selector, this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="user-profile-post-actual" id="profile-post-{{ $profilePost->id }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First move the setTimeout below the loading data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var selector = $('.tab-panels li.active');
            if (selector.hasClass('active')) {
                var panelToShow = $(selector).attr('rel');
                $('#' + panelToShow).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
                var url = window.location.hash;
                var hash = url.split('#').pop();
                console.log(hash);
                history.pushState(null, null, '?' + panelToShow + '#' + hash);
                var target = window.location.hash;
                //console.log(target);

                    //$('html, body').animate({
                    //    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                    //}, 1000);
                    //$(document).scrollTop($(window.location.hash).offset().top);
                    //$.scrollTo(window.location.hash);
                    document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            } else {
                var selector = $('.tab-panels li:nth-of-type(1)');
                var panelToShow = $(selector).attr('rel');
                $('#' + panelToShow).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
                var url = window.location.hash;
                var hash = url.split('#').pop();
                console.log(hash);
                history.pushState(null, null, '?' + panelToShow + '#' + hash);
                var target = window.location.hash;
                    //console.log(target);
                    //$('html, body').animate({
                    //    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                    //}, 1000);
                   //$(document).scrollTop($(window.location.hash).offset().top);
                   //$.scrollTo(window.location.hash);
                   document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
                $(selector, this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        setTimeout(function () {
            //document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
            //$.scrollTo(window.location.hash);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    });
```